# Chain query in Linq

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I have the following queries:

```
var ground = db
    .Ground
    .Where(g => g.RowKey == Ground_Uuid)
    .ToList();

var building = db
    .Building
    .Where(b => ground.Any(gr => gr.RowKey == b.Ground.RowKey))
    .ToList();

var floor = db
    .Floor
    .Where(b => building.Any(by => by.RowKey == b.Building.RowKey))
    .ToList();
```

So the second relies on the id from the first set and so on. 
I got following error when an execution goes to the second query:

> Unable to create a constant value of type 'Domain.Model.Entities.Ground'. Only primitive types or enumeration types are supported in this context.

Any ideas how to resolve it?

Comment: What Ground_Uuid is? I'd blindly guess it can't be converted to SQL query. Use an ID or something else...

Comment: Try removing the `ToList` from the first two queries.

Comment: it is just simple int

Comment: Remove ToList() from first two. You are making them local enumerables but you need IQueryable.

Comment: Couldn't you just do `var floor = db.Floor.Where(f => f.Building.Ground.RowKey == Ground_Uuid);` instead?

Answer (score 2):

The problem with your code is that `ToList` is converting the result into an in-memory object and a collection of objects in memory cannot be joined with a set of data in the database.

```
var ground = db.Ground.Where(g => g.RowKey == Ground_Uuid);
var building = db.Building.Where(b => ground.Any(gr => gr.RowKey == b.Ground.RowKey));
var floor = db.Floor.Where(b => building.Any(by => by.RowKey == b.Building.RowKey));
```

Also, frankly after reading @juharr's comment, I saw the relationship between floor, building & ground. Since you are already doing `b.Building.RowKey`, `b.Ground.RowKey` predicting the relationship was easy and I totally agree, it can be simplified as:-

```
var floor = db.Floor.Where(b => b.Building.Ground.RowKey == Ground_Uuid);
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems like the first query is redundant. You already know that the `RowKey` column for each row will be equal to `Ground_Uuid`.

```
var building = db.Building.Where(b => b.Ground.RowKey == Ground_Uuid);
var floor = db.Floor.Where(b => b.Building.Ground.RowKey == Ground_Uuid);
```

Comment: That should be `b => b.Building.Ground.RowKey == Ground_Uuid` for `floor`.

Comment: You're missing the `Ground` part now though.

Comment: @juharr It doesn't have one in the question. Am I missing something?

Comment: Each `Floor` has a `Building` property and each `Building` has a `Ground` property.  So it looks like it should be `b.Building.Groud.RowKey == Ground_Uuid`.

Answer (score 1):

Removing ToList() would do the job, but moreover if RowKey is the foreign key you can utilize Linq:

```
var floor = db.Floor
    .Where(b => b.Building.Ground.RowKey == Ground_Uuid)
    .ToList();
```

Comment: I don't think `Floor` has a one to many relationship to `Building`.

Comment: You may never know, you are assuming from the names instead of factual data. Anyway, I already edited it to be a single entity before your message.

Comment: No, I'm saying that the `Building` property of each `Floor` is a single building object, not a list and therefore you cannot use `Any`.  It seems pretty obvious from the use of `b.Building.RowKey` in the last query in the question.

Comment: Oh the queires are edited, you are right. I will edit.